# Run single nodejs script which require 3rd party modules, without presetting package.json/package-lock.json. (npx?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, npm, npx

How can I run a nodejs script which require other 3rd-party node modules, without having to install the external module beforehand and without having to setup **package.json / package-lock.json** files?

e.x. I was trying to achieve this with npx, but couldn't make it work.

```
npx -p lodash -c "node test.js"
```

content of test.js:

```
const _ = require('lodash')
console.log(_.constant(1))
```

> I know I can do `npm i lodash` or `npm i -g lodash` first and then run the script, but my question is different